# Why do I get different results for Google API place search from web browser versus from Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, google-places-api

I'm trying to use Google Places API to search for places from an Excel Spreadsheet, returning their place id, longitude and latitude.

When I use the API from my browser with this URL,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/xml?key=MYKEY&input=%22saint%20mary,%20reading%20berkshire%22&inputtype=textquery&fields=place_id,geometry/location
```

I get these results:

```
<FindPlaceFromTextResponse>
<candidates>
<geometry>
<location>
<lat>51.4544683</lat>
<lng>-0.9739627</lng>
</location>
</geometry>
<place_id>ChIJC-64rxabdkgRxjqxVE0q21k</place_id>
</candidates>
<status>OK</status>
</FindPlaceFromTextResponse>
```

However, running the same request from an Excel VBA module returns the following:
[image: ChIJByZmrxabdkgR96wuqh0HTN0]

Close, but not quite the same. I think the first one is a church and the second is a nearby business. Is there any way I can make these return the same results? Or any reason why the results are different?

Here is my VBA code for sending the http request. The "ConcatenateRow" function just concatenates the range of cells that I pass to the function, separating them with spaces. Those cells containt "saint mary, reading" and "berkshire."

```
Function GMapsGeocode(address As Range) As Variant
    'returns the Google place id, latitude and longitude
    If myKey = "" Then myKey = InputBox("What's your Google API Key?")
    Dim addressConcat As String: addressConcat = ConcatenateRow(address, " ")
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    'strAddress = URLEncode(addressConcat)
    Dim Returns(2) As Variant

    'Assemble the query string
    strQuery = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/xml?"
    strQuery = strQuery & "key=" & myKey
    strQuery = strQuery & "&input=" & addressConcat
    strQuery = strQuery & "&inputtype=textquery&fields=place_id,geometry/location"

    'define XML and HTTP components
    Dim googleResult As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim googleService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim firstResult As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim oNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    googleService.Open "GET", strQuery, False
    googleService.send
    googleResult.LoadXML (googleService.responseText)
```

In effect, the two queries should be the same. I'm at a loss as to why they're not. Help welcome.

Comment: What does your strQuery look like before sending it to the googleService.Open? I'm wondering if it has something to do with the URL encoding?

Comment: So I actually commented out the URL encode function because I thought the same thing. It's now just passing a raw string as the input.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/xml?key=MYKEY&input=saint mary, reading berkshire&inputtype=textquery&fields=place_id,geometry/location

Comment: I get the same thing if I pass this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/xml?key=MYKEY&input=saint%20mary%2C%20reading%20berkshire&inputtype=textquery&fields=place_id,geometry/location

Comment: I notice that the link you posted in the comment doesn't quite match the initial link you have. In your input it's missing the Encoding for the quotation marks before and after, and the comma is encoded in one vs. the other.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/xml?key=MYKEY&input=saint%20mary%2C%20reading%20berkshire&inputtype=textquery&fields=place_id,geometry/location

vs. 

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/xml?key=MYKEY&input=%22saint%20mary,%20reading%20berkshire%22&inputtype=textquery&fields=place_id,geometry/location

Comment: Your comment motivated my to experiment with the URLs a bit more. It looks like including quotations marks  or not in the URL is important in determining the result. Presumably this is because it doesn't allow for permutations of the keywords?

Comment: So would updating this line to the following work: 
strQuery = strQuery & "&input=" & Chr(34) & addressConcat & Chr(34)

This would add the quotation marks.